# How to create a directory using StreamWriter?

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to create a directory using StreamWriter?

Comment: whomever downmodded this needs a head check. It's a valid question (admittedly though, easily googled).

Comment: Snorfus, perhaps the person thought the question was unclear. Also, it's "whoever," not "whomever."

Comment: ironically, the google search "create directory streamwriter" comes here

Answer (score 25):

No. You can't actually create a directory using a StreamWriter. Use [Directory.CreateDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.createdirectory.aspx) instead.

If you're trying to read the directory name out of a file stream and then create a file based on that text, you'll need something like this:

```
FileStream fs; // this is the filestream from somewhere. make sure to dispose it
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(fs))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(r.ReadToEnd());
```

Comment: Yes I know about the Directory.CreateDirectory but to CreateDirectory you can only pass a string. I need to pass a FileStream

Comment: Arif, how do you expect to create a directory based on the *contents* of a file?

Comment: Sorry I am not clear about your question? I never said I am not expecting to a create a directory based on the *contents* of a file. Please clarify

Comment: You mean, you want to use what's in a FileStream as the name of a folder?

Comment: but what's in a FileStream is the contents of a file?

Comment: Maybe it just has the name of the directory to create?